# How to get the parameter value from ApplicationParameters files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have Azure Service Fabric project and it contains ApplicationParameters folder for configuration files. Please check the below pic.

[image: xmlfiles]

I want to read the value of the "EndPoint" parameter from the "Local.1Node.xml" file in my C# code.

**Local.1Node.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/Pharmerica.EMessaging.Inbound.Processor.Asf" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="EndPoint" Value="www.abc.com/api/get" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

**C#:**

From app.config file we can read like below.

```
var endPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPoint"];
```

How can one read it in, in the case of Azure Service Fabric project?

Answer (score 1):

I had to go two ways about it. There is no native way of reading in the parameter that I know of at this time.

- **Using a Method** to look up a value from parsed XML.
- **Using REGEX** to fix XML before parsing and getting the value

**Function**

You can retrieve the Value from your XML file by using a method that should work on every xml file. Provide a few basic things and you should get the value (if it exists, null otherwise). Following is a recursive approach from top to bottom.

```
    public static string GetValueForAttribute(XmlNode element, string elementName, string attribute)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        if (element.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in element.ChildNodes)
            {
                value = GetValueForAttribute(node, elementName, attribute);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    return value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (element.Name.Equals(elementName) && element.Attributes["Name"].Value.Equals(attribute))
                return element.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToString();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Usage for the above method is ...

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path + XMLFileName);

    string value = GetValueForAttribute(doc.DocumentElement, "Parameter", "EndPoint");
```

**Regex**

The other way to go about reading your XML is by removing the namespaces in the elements. Following method was derived [from this site.](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/113-c-reading-xml-with-namespace)

```
    string filter = @"xmlns(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""|xsi(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""";
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(path + XMLFileName);
    string filteredFile = Regex.Replace(fileContent, filter, "");

    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc2.Load(Path + XMLFileName);

    string value = doc2.SelectNodes("//Application/Parameters/Parameter")
                       .Cast<XmlNode>() // Converts the Collection to List
                       .Where(x => x.Attributes["Name"].Value.Equals("EndPoint"))
                       .Select(x => x.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToString())
                       .FirstOrDefault(); // First would be value .. default would be null.

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        Console.WriteLine(value);
```